# Accessibility mode does not work properly with margin or padding on iframe

Tags: angular, angularjs, capacitor

I have an application, on the main page I have a header, in the middle I have an iframe, and below I have a footer.
iframe holds pages in old angularJS code.
The problem I'm facing is that if I use margins or padding on an iframe in accessibility mode I get focus inside the iframe but if I try to click the buttons they don't click.
I use an iPhone with a margin safe area, so I encounter this problem.
I would appreciate advice on how to solve this.